# How do I Facet_wrap without repeating coordinate values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am trying to create a plot which contains a discrete variable in one of the axis. I am furthermore trying to group these variables with respect to another variable and represent it in a graph using ggplot2. The code I have used is as follows:

```r
size_vs_paper %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Reference,y=S_Max)) +       
        theme_classic()+
        geom_segment(aes(xend =Reference,yend = S_Min),size=0.5) +
        #geom_text(size = 5, vjust=-3) +
        geom_point(aes(group = Environment), size = 3, shape = "|", color = "black", alpha = 0.7)+
        geom_point(aes(y=S_Min, group = Environment), size = 3, shape = "|", color = "black", alpha = 0.7) +
        geom_point(aes(y=S_Mean, group = Environment), size = 3, color = "black", alpha = 0.7) +
        facet_wrap(Environment ~ ., ncol = 1) +
        scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set2") +
        scale_y_log10(breaks=c(0.01,1,10,100,1000, 5000, 10000)) +
        theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 10),
              legend.position = "none") +
        coord_flip() +
        labs(y = "Size (µm)")
```

This yields the graph as below:
[image]

As you can see, the Y axis representing the references repeats itself for all the facets. I am looking to facet them without the references repeating themselves. Any guidance will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for the `scales = "free_y"` argument of `facet_wrap()`?